# good practices of VBC views

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a question about class-based views.

I have the following view:

```
class UserCourseListView(ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'courses/user_course_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_inscriptions = self.request.user.get_inscriptions.all()
        courses = [inscription.course for inscription in user_inscriptions]

        return courses
```

The purpose of the view is to obtain a list of the courses in which the user who logged in at that time has registered. And be able to access that data in context (in the template).

---

The doubt I have is the following:

The `model` class attribute is the`User` model and in the `get_queryset` estoy method returning instances of the`Course` model, which does not make much sense.

And my question is, is it good practice to do this?

Is there another better way to do it with class-based views?

---

Another way I came up with it and that is more consistent is with a function-based view, but it doesn't convince me much:

```
def user_course_list(request):
    user_inscriptions = request.user.get_inscriptions.all()
    courses = [inscription.course for inscription in user_inscriptions]

    return render('courses/user_course_list.html', {'courses': courses})
```

Since Django documentation recommends that we use class-based views as much as possible.

**UPDATE:**

My file `models.py`:

```
# --- --- COURSE MODEL --- ---

class Course(models.Model):
    STATUS = [('unpublish', 'No publicar'),('published', 'Publicar')]
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2, default = 0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = manage_courses_media_files)
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 60, choices = STATUS, default = 'unpublish')
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'get_courses')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 60)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created', '-updated']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

# --- --- INSCRIPTION MODEL --- ---

class Inscription(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name = 'Curso')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name = 'Usuario', related_name = 'get_inscriptions')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, verbose_name = 'Fecha de inscripcion')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'inscripcion'
        verbose_name_plural = 'inscripciones'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entireally sure how your models are setup, but when making a viewset for a specific model, you would set it up similar to what I wrote below. Course would be the model, `inscription_set` would be the related name if course is a foreign key on inscription. Now you may have set the related_key name yourself on the model and could switch that out. I am guessing inscriptions store a user_id? I am not sure what your model manager is doing with `.get_inscriptions`.

```
class UserCourseListView(ListView):
    model = Course
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    template_name = 'courses/user_course_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        courses = self.queryset.filter(inscription_set__get_inscriptions=request.user)
        return courses.all()
```

Comment: I get an error, but I think you're close to solving my problem, I already updated my question showing my models

Comment: Changed the related name from `user` to `get_inscriptions` based on your edits, let me know if that works.

Comment: `Cannot resolve keyword 'inscription_set' into field. Choices are: cart, created, description, get_sections, id, image, inscription, instructor, instructor_id, price, slug, status, subtitle, title, updated`

Comment: oh change it to inscription then, that must be the related_name

Comment: I don't understand you, explain me better

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, changing the `related_name` to the` Foreign Key`  `course`

Comment: So: `Course.objects.filter(get_inscriptions__user = self.request.user)`

Comment: Remove the `related_name` from the` Foreign Key` and manage to do the same with the following queryset: `Course.objects.filter(inscription__user = self.request.user)`

Comment: with `inscription_set` does not work, only with` inscription __user`, do you know why?

Comment: `inscription_set` is just a guess on the related name, the error you posted makes me think the related name is inscription...you can also add one to the model yourself and use that.